# cannot safely remove external hard drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I am facing a similar situation with this [here](https://superuser.com/questions/87364/can-windows-tell-me-what-is-using-my-usb-drive),the only 2 differences being that I am facing the problem with an external HDD and in win7.

I tried this solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/510968/external-hdd-is-always-in-use-when-trying-to-safely-remove)-using Sysinternals Process Explorer to find and stop handles related to the external HDD.I found 2 explorer handles related to the HDD,nevertheless the drive still,could not be ejected from the PC even after the handles were stopped..
What can I do to find what is keeping the drive from ejecting safely.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/

Make sure to say NO to the optional toolbar.
This will tell you what is locking the drive and unlock it if necessary.

Comment: no, unlocker did not solve the problem.It did find the locking processes(2) but "killing" them did not make possible  removing safely the external HDD.The problem remains-I do not know what to try next.just want to add that the processes found were explorer.exe

Comment: @DimitrisPapageorgiou  **explorer.exe** Auto re-spawns as it is necessary for windows.  Close all "Windows Explorer" or My computer windows you have open.  Then instead of killing the process, use **unlock all** and then **Safely Remove**.  Otherwise you will have to turn the computer off, unplug the drive and turn PC back on which would be dumb.

Comment: That did not work either.Two handles were found,I used unlock all as you said and despite the fact that these were "killed" the HDD could still not be removed.